# Generate a nested structure based on a list of file paths

Tags: javascript, node.js, file-system

I'm currently working on a small application, as a learning exercise for a Javascript novice. I need to generate an object based on a folder structure. Here is an example of the folder structure:

> RootFolder/FolderA/FolderB/FileA
>
> RootFolder/FolderA/FolderB/FileB
>
> RootFolder/FolderA/FolderB/FolderC/FileA
>
> RootFolder/FolderA/FolderB/FolderC/FileB

The desired resulting object should have the following structure:

```
{
    RootFolder: {
        FolderA: {
            FolderB: {
                FileA: {},
                FileB: {},
                FolderC: {
                    FileA: {},
                    FileB: {}
                }
            }
        }
    }
};
```

So far I came up with the following code and it seems to be doing the job, but I'm concerned with 'eval' use and generally believe there is a more elegant way of doing it.

```js
module.exports = {
  structure: function(structureArray) {
    var generatedObject = {};
    for (var i = 0; i < structureArray.length; i++) {
      var objectElements = '';
      var path = (structureArray[i].split('/')).filter(Boolean);
      for (var l = 0; l < path.length; l++) {
        if (objectElements.indexOf(path[l]) == -1 || path[l].length == 1) {
          objectElements += '["' + path[l] + '"]';
        }
        if (!(eval('generatedObject' + objectElements))) {
          eval('generatedObject' + objectElements + '= {}')
        }
      }
    }
    return generatedObject;
  }
};
```

`structureArray` contains full path strings as in the folder structure example above (e.g. `'RootFolder/FolderA/FolderB/FileA'`)

Comment: I would use paths delimited with dot `.` like this : `['RootFolder/FolderA/FolderB/FileA','RootFolder/FolderA/FolderB/FileB', '...']` and use `_.set` https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.4#set

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can split each path at `/` using `split` and then use `reduce()` to build that object.

```js
var paths = [
  'RootFolder/FolderA/FolderB/FileA',
  'RootFolder/FolderA/FolderB/FileB',
  'RootFolder/FolderA/FolderB/FolderC/FileA',
  'RootFolder/FolderA/FolderB/FolderC/FileB'
]

var obj = {}
paths.forEach(function(path) {
  path.split('/').reduce(function(r, e) {
    return r[e] || (r[e] = {})
  }, obj)
})

console.log(obj)
```

Here is how you can use this approach to read some directory and all of its nested content and create object from that. This approach is synchronous.

```js
var fs = require('fs');
var path = require('path');

var p = path.resolve('C:\\your\\path\\here')
var result = {}

function buildObject(startPath) {
  var dir = fs.readdirSync(startPath)
  dir.forEach(function(e) {
    var newPath = path.join(startPath, e)

    var stat = fs.statSync(newPath);
    if (stat && stat.isDirectory()) buildObject(newPath)
    if (stat.isFile()) {
      newPath.split('\\').reduce(function(r, a) {
        return r[a] || (r[a] = {})
      }, result)
    }
  })
}

buildObject(p)
console.log(result)
```

Comment: sorry my ignorance, but how could remove the `"file.jpg": {}`, when it is a file

Comment: @VitorHugo You can replace the `return` line with this `return r[e] || (e.indexOf(".")==-1?(r[e] = {}):r[e]="")` but beware, you'll have to handle this while reading.

Comment: @ShivamSharma no and what I'm looking for, your solution just exchanged brackets for quotes, what I'm trying to and remove the brackets from the files, convert the files into simple value, thanks for trying to help me. - https://prnt.sc/usvfyh

Answer (score 5):

Although the previous answer does solve OP's needs, I believe an asynchronous non-blocking approach would help making the code more concise and easy to use, whilst also avoiding explicit calls to stats.

We can use ES6 async generators to walk (read) our directories:

```
import { join } from 'path'
import { opendir } from 'fs/promises'

async function* walk(root) {
  for await (const entry of await opendir(root)) {
    const path = join(root, entry.name)
    if (entry.isDirectory()) yield* await walk(path)
    else if (entry.isFile()) yield path
  }
}
```

Then iterate over them like so:

```
for await (const path of walk('path/to/dir')) {
  console.log(path)
}
```

We'd then be able to build our tree using an IIFE (Immediately Invoked Function Expression) inside a `.js` file.

```
;(async () => {
  let tree = {}
  for await (const path of walk('../../my-dir')) {
    path.split('/').reduce((o, k) => (o[k] = o[k] ||  {}), tree)
  }
  console.log(JSON.stringify(tree, null, 2))
})()
```